# Error with struktex making a Case

Tags: struktex

I am writing a document with TeX using TexLive (Ubuntu), I already installed `struktex`, it works fine with `if` and `assing`, but when i try to make a `case` statement throw an error.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{struktex}

\begin{document}

\begin{struktogramm}(95,30)
    \case[10]{4}{3}{Signum(x)}{-1}
        \assign{\(a \gets - \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \switch{0}
        \assign{Output: Division by 0}
    \switch{1}
        \assign{\(a \gets \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \caseend
\end{struktogramm}

\end{document}
```

And the errors:

> ```
> ./TestCase.tex:23:Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra } \switch{0}
> ./TestCase.tex:23:Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg~ was complete \switch{0}
> ./TestCase.tex:25:Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra } \switch{1}
> ./TestCase.tex:25:Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg~ was complete \switch{1}
> ```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is mentioned in the manual of Spanish babel
www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/spanish.pdf
Should work with `\renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish]{book}

\usepackage{babel}
\renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{struktex}

\begin{document}

\begin{struktogramm}(95,30)
    \case[10]{4}{3}{Signum(x)}{-1}
        \assign{\(a \gets - \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \switch{0}
        \assign{Output: Division by 0}
    \switch{1}
        \assign{\(a \gets \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \caseend
\end{struktogramm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still keep most of the shorthands by passing the `es-notilde` option to `babel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish]{book}

\usepackage[es-notilde]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{struktex}

\begin{document}

\begin{struktogramm}(95,30)
    \case[10]{4}{3}{Signum(x)}{-1}
        \assign{\(a \gets - \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \switch{0}
        \assign{Output: Division by 0}
    \switch{1}
        \assign{\(a \gets \frac{1}{x}\)}
    \caseend
\end{struktogramm}

\end{document}
```

Using the tilde as shorthand for Spanish is deprecated anyway.

Saying `\renewcommand\shorthandsspanish{}` will disallow *all* shorthands. This is more conveniently obtained by passing the `es-noshorthands` option to `babel`.